# check value in xml tag with sql

Tags: sql, xml, tags

I'm trying to get and check some attribute value in the xml document.
Tag:

```
<СведТов НомСтр="" НаимТов="" ОКЕИ_Тов="7966" КолТов="" ЦенаТов="" СтТовБезНДС="" НалСт="" СтТовУчНал="">
</СведТов>
```

I've tried next:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 as b ON a.intDocID=b.intDocID 
LEFT JOIN table3 as c ON a.intDocID = c.intOneDocID
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONVERT( c.varBody USING cp1251 ) , 'ОКЕИ_Тов="', -1), '"', 1) > 999 and 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONVERT( c.varBody USING cp1251 ) , 'ОКЕИ_Тов="', -1), '"', 1) < 10000 and
a.intSendTimestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-08-11 23:59:59')
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: What Database system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql you can use EXTRACTVALUE

Something like

```
ExtractValue(c.varBody, '//СведТов/@ОКЕИ_Тов')
```

This works anyway

```
create table foo(varBody text);
insert into foo (varBody) values
(
  '<СведТов НомСтр="" НаимТов="" ОКЕИ_Тов="7966" КолТов="" ЦенаТов="" СтТовБезНДС="" НалСт="" СтТовУчНал="">
</СведТов> '   
  );

SELECT ExtractValue(varBody, '//СведТов/@ОКЕИ_Тов')
from foo;
```